Sourcetree not starting after a Windows 11 update
After automatically updating Windows 11, Sourcetree failed to launch. It just seemed it was being opened until proving that nope.
What can I do to fix it?

I went to C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Atlassian and deleted all folders in exception of the SourceTree one. For clarity, the folders I deleted had names similar to  SourceTree.exe_Url_pnpikom25tpi0kbkzfttngnk42p3r1vp.
After that, Sourcetree launched successfully.
